# SQL - only display rows that have the max value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table that is already sorted but I want it to only display the maximum values... so instead of this table:

```
+------+-------+
| id   | value | 
+------+-------+
| 1    |  3    | 
| 5    |  3    |
| 4    |  3    |
| 9    |  2    | 
| 8    |  2    |
| 3    |  2    |
| 2    |  1    |
| 6    |  1    |
| 7    |  1    |
+------+-------+
```

I want this:

```
+------+-------+
| id   | value | 
+------+-------+
| 1    |  3    | 
| 5    |  3    |
| 4    |  3    |
+------+-------+
```

I'm using SQLite. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a subquery.  Here is one way:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value = (select max(value) from t);
```